# Locking Skewer slipping from rear wheel dropout

Tags: rear-wheel, dropouts, skewer

I recently purchased new locking skewers ([Kyrptonite WheelNutz](http://www.kryptonitelock.com/en/products/product-information/current-key/001751.html)) and they're slipping out of rear wheel dropout with little force. I've noticed they have zero bite on the nut compared to other skewers.

[image]

[image]

More pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6beVm.jpg

Comment: I personally wouldn't be comfortable using such a product -- it doesn't really add security. Disc brakes are good at loosening skewers too, to begin with. Its slipping cause it can't get tight enough. You need to make sure the tab is at the bottom of the dropout and tighten the bejeezus out of it to have the best shot. And I'd still not be comfortable that its tight enough to hold without teeth to bite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience this is a problem with all such products. I use [Pitlocks](https://www.pitlock.de/en/shop/quick-release-protection-more/set-01-en.html) on my bikes and while they have slightly more corrugated interiors, they still slip. I have once sent a bike to be serviced and the shop extracted the Pit-locked rear wheel without damaging the bike or Pitlock. They said it was easier than making me post them the key.

[image]

Since my bikes are steel, it was easy enough for me to put a few spots of weld on the rear dropouts to stop that happening again. In your case it looks like an aluminium frame and aluminium locking surface, so putting "teeth" on either isn't going to help - the metal is too soft. Having a bigger barrier similar to the "lawyer lips" on a front dropout makes the locking skewer work.

So I don't think the problem is with the lack of teeth on the skewer directly, it's with the whole concept.